# CanFreeze is returning false because a DependencyProperty on the Freezable has a value that is an expression

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm binding a `Brush` to a `StaticResource` and the debugger keeps throwing warnings at me that it cannot freeze the brush.

> CanFreeze is returning false because a DependencyProperty on the
> Freezable has a value that is an expression;
>
> ```
> Freezable='#FFFF3B30';    
> Freezable.HashCode='9502070';   
> Freezable.Type='System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush';    
> DP='Color';    
> DpOwnerType='System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush'
> ```

What I want to do is define a palette of colors - then reference one of the colors, defining it as something like `Theme.Colors.Highlight`. Then I wanna create 20 shades of this color - referencing `Theme.Colors.Highlight` now.

Simplified example

```
<Color x:Key="Pink" R="255" G="45"  B="85"  A="255" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Pink}}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor[-100%]" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyColor}, 
                                                Converter={StaticResource Brightness},
                                                ConverterParameter=-1.0}" />
<!-- ... -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor[100%]" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyColor}, 
                                               Converter={StaticResource Brightness},
                                               ConverterParameter=1.0}" />
```

So *if* I understand the problem correctly WPF is complaining that it can't freeze the `Brush` because it has a binding. Correct? I'm kinda surprised since the root of all these bindings still is a hard-coded value. Also it's not even a `DynamicResource`. As far as I understand `StaticResource`s are wired at compile time.

Basically my question is: Can I avoid this problem somehow?
Without the obvious solution: hard-coding the colors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sort of 'hacking' the `Binding` to use your own converter to modify a static source. You can actually make this a lot cleaner (and it will probably be freezable too) if you write your own custom [MarkupExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/markup-extensions-for-xaml-overview). It won't be that different from making an `IValueConverter`, but you can use it directly anywhere in xaml, instead of just inside bindings.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Color))]
public class BrightnessExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("color")]
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("brightness")]
    public double Brightness { get; set; }

    public BrightnessMarkupExtension() { }

    public BrightnessMarkupExtension(Color color, double brightness)
    {
        Color = color;
        Brightness = brightness;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return //<do something with Color and Brightness here>;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your XAML like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Pink}}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor[-100%]" Color="{my:Brightness {StaticResource Pink}, -1.0} />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor[100%]" Color="{my:Brightness {StaticResource Pink}, 1.0} />
```

Comment: It's still throwing the same warnings at me.